# Why doesn't the StackExchange twitter feed follow The Great Outdoors' twitter feed?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I couldn't find one in the "following" tab of [StackExchange](https://twitter.com/StackExchange/following) and at first assumed it didn't exist. I guess (right) that it would have the same format as the others, and that's how I found it - [StackOutdoors](https://twitter.com/StackOutdoors). Is there any reason why the main StackExchange account doesn't follow it? That would help people to know about us.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed. Apologies!

You're re-connected to the twitterverse.

Comment: Hooray! And we appear first, which is sure to help people to notice us.

Comment: Thanks Jaydles! Much appreciated!